# Loading in noconflict doesn't appear to be working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a WooCommerce website and I'm just starting to fiddle with a few things. I've made a small floating menu with the logo that appears on scroll, but I'm having trouble with noconflict. It doesn't appear to be working.

When someone enters their card number at checkout I get a warning to enter a card number, or if I'm a developer to make sure there isn't a JQuery conflict.

I remove the code I made and the checkout works and there's no message.
This is what I have. Please let me know if I messed anything up.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jqu = $.noConflict();
jqu(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = jqu(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        jqu('.bottomMenu').slideDown();
    } else {
        jqu('.bottomMenu').slideUp();
    }
});
jqu(function(){
    jqu(".bottomMenu").hide();
});
</script>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

First you should try this instead, because wordpress use **`jQuery`** and not the **`$`** shorthand.

This is your changed code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        jQuery('.bottomMenu').slideDown();
    } else {
        jQuery('.bottomMenu').slideUp();
    }
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(".bottomMenu").hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

After is better to use [**`wp_enqueue_script()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function putting your custom script in an external **`.js`** files, into your theme folder (here in a **`js`** subfolder in your theme folder).

You could use something like this (in **`function.php`** file of your active theme):

```
function enqueuing_my_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueuing_my_scripts' );
```

As query is already in wordpress, you don't need anything else than your custom js file script.

> If you are using **child theme**, then you will replace **`get_template_directory_uri()`** function by **`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`** instead.

Comment: Thanks for information LoicTheAztec. The code didn't work, but your explanation about wordpress and jquery pointed me in the right direction.
What I did was remove the $ completely, got rid of the noconflict and just used jquery. The problem is solved. Thanks heaps. I suppose I suffered from a novice mistake. Lots to learn, but I love doing it. It's fun to see something come alive.